# Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mysql2' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose

I am setting up a NodeJS + Mysql + Typescript + Docker app, but have a problem when I try to include the `mysql2` npm package in my main script. In fact, whenever I include the script I get this error: `Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mysql2' or its corresponding type declarations.`.

Here are my files:

```
// src/index.ts

import 'dotenv/config';

import express, { Application, Request, Response } from 'express';
import mysql from 'mysql2';

const app: Application = express();

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
});
const db = pool.promise();

// App
app.use(express.json());
app.get('/', async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const results = await db.query('SELECT * FROM my_table');

  [...]
});

app.listen(process.env.NODE_LOCAL_PORT, () => {
  [...]
});
```

```
// package.json

{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.4.13",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.0"
  }
}
```

```
// Dockerfile

FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app/
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
COPY . /
```

```
// docker-compose.yaml

version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    env_file: ./.env
    command: yarn start
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - $NODE_LOCAL_PORT:$NODE_DOCKER_PORT
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
    ports:
      - $MYSQL_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQL_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - mysql_config:/etc/mysql

volumes:
  mysql:
  mysql_config:
```

Any idea of why I keep having this issue?

Comment: Typescript can't resolve `mysql2`. Does `mysql2` have an associated @types module, e.g. `@types/mysql2`? If not, you can declare a typing in a `.d.ts` file

Comment: @Dom, yes, it does (i also double checked in `node_modules`)!